# convexity of a function involving inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

The function has the following form:
$f(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2) = bA^{-1}c$, where
\begin{align*}
b&=\pmatrix{0,&\frac{a_1}{a_1-t_1},&\frac{a_2}{a_2-t_2},&\frac{b_1}{b_1-t_1}+\frac{b_2}{b_2-t_2}},\\
c&=(0,0,0,1)^T,\\
A&=\pmatrix{
t_1+t_2 &-a_1+t_1    &-a_2+t_2    &0\\
-t_1    &a_1-t_1+t_2 &0           &-b_2+t_2\\
-t_2    &0           &a_2+t_1-t_2 &-b_1+t_1\\
1       &1           &1           &1}.
\end{align*}
We also have the constraints $a_1>b_1>t_1>0$ and $a_2>b_2>t_2>0$.

I've been working on proving $f$ is convex in $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$ for quite a while. Hope to get some suggestions on this forum.

PS: Convexity is always observed in numerical examples.